# HashMap or HashTable?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I need to read a file:
.txt(
key1|username1
key2|null
key3|username3
key4|null
key5|username5
)... search for a user with the key and change the user name. What has better runtime? (It is a very simple program)

Comment: Use `HashMap`. `HashTable` is obsolete.

Comment: hashmap is faster hashtable is thread-safe. I strongly recomend hashmap or concurrenthashmap.

Answer (score 1):

You should use HashMap if there are no concurrent clients reading the files, otherwise use HashTable or ConcurrentHashMap.